# Surface fall off while sculpting?

Tags: sculpting

Recent Blender switcher here so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm trying out Blenders sculpting features. ( Very nice) But I can't seem to figure out how to do surface fall off on the brushes. eg. I have a head model and the mouth is closed, I want to use the elastic brush to seperate the lips. But the fall off means every time I try move the top lip the bottom lip moves too. In other software ( XSI and Maya) I could chose surface as the fall off method to get around this issue.
Is there a similar setting in blender that I'm missing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correcly what you want, you could use *Face Sets* or the *Mask* brush (shortcut <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to remove) to preserve an area:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's what Ive resorted to doing. Is there a way to save a mask that you use often? Or even a way to convert a face set into a mask?

Comment: You can create a vertex group, select its vertices, then Face Sets > Face Set from Edit Mode Selection. Maybe there's another way...

Comment: Ok, I found it! (sort of)
If you check the topology option on the Advanced tab > Auto-mask of the brush it does what I'm looking for. Sadly it only seems to work on the grab brush.

Comment: Oh ok so it only affects the connected faces I guess